# How do I scrape the data from the Google Docs table on this web page?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use Python to scrape the data from the table on this web page.

http://www.dividendyieldhunter.com/exchanged-traded-debt-issues-sorted-alphabetically/

I tried using requests and bs4. I get the raw HTML but it looks like the data is hidden. What should I be trying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular page is loading the data from a URL in an iFrame in this code:

```
<iframe id="pageswitcher-content" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HY2XEBKcyi4STki-uUbOfr-su8CZOfpi-jM1Racwyw/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&amp;gid=0" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

You would need to further request the HTML from the URL in the src attribute at:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HY2XEBKcyi4STki-uUbOfr-su8CZOfpi-jM1Racwyw/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&amp;gid=0
```

Then you could scrape the table with the class="waffle".

NOTE: Take care with the URL query parameters that come from the raw URL as in the example below.

For example the `&amp;` near the end must be converted to a single & character for the requests module to find the proper URL, e.g.

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HY2XEBKcyi4STki-uUbOfr-su8CZOfpi-jM1Racwyw/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0")
print(res.text)
```

Comment: So if I use requests with the iframe ip address and then print the result, I don't see a table or any data.

Comment: @ Turnkey 

So if I use requests with the iframe ip address and then print the result, I don't see a table or any data.

import requests
res=request.get(''https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HY2XEBKcyi4STki-uUbOfr-su8CZOfpi-jM1Racwyw/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&amp;gid=0'
print(res.text)

Comment: I think there is something going on blocking when trying to get it by itself.  Let me do another test and get back with you.

Comment: There is a problem with the URL in that the &amp; needs to be converted to an actual & for the requests code.  I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: that worked ! Thanks so much. A couple of questions though. How did you figure that out ? How would one know the &amp ; part of the url string was inappropriate ? How does the table actually update if the string in the iframe is not right ?

Any info would be appreciated. Just want to learn.

Comment: You're welcome, I suspected it just from experience with web.  I think the browser is a little more forgiving than the Python requests which explains why it worked there.  Usually the & is a delimiter between URL query parameters and shouldn't be encoded like that as part of a URL. Here's some more information about the structure and what's permitted in URL's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier